# Data format change while writing to a file connection R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data, for which reproducible example set is:

```
a<-data.frame(
MDSE_ITEM_I=as.factor(c(rep(10,2),rep(15,2),rep(23,4))),
CO_LOC_I=as.factor(c(rep(1,2),rep(3,2),rep(5,1),rep(7,3))),
date = seq(as.Date("2011-12-01"), as.Date("2011-12-08"),by="days"),
SLS_TYPE_GRP_C=as.factor(c(rep("R",2),rep("P",4),rep("P",2))),
NON_CLR_SLS_Q=as.numeric(rnorm(8,3,1)))
```

Which I am trying to write into a file connection using cat command:

```
fileConn<-file("/Users/z076156/Desktop/output.txt")
sapply(1:nrow(a), FUN = function(row) {
  cat(a$MDSE_ITEM_I[row],",",a$CO_LOC_I[row],",",a$date[row],",",
      a$SLS_TYPE_GRP_C[row],",",a$NON_CLR_SLS_Q[row],"\n",sep='')})
close(fileConn)
```

The output I get is:

```
1,1,15309,2,3.043244
1,1,15310,2,2.667343
2,2,15311,1,1.177765
2,2,15312,1,4.411262
3,3,15313,1,2.162418
3,4,15314,1,1.876237
3,4,15315,1,6.043766
3,4,15316,1,3.235021
```

This output is stripped of the `factor` and `date` formatting. How can I maintain formatting while writing to a file connection?

Comment: Why not just use `write.csv(a, "output.txt", row.names=FALSE)`?

Comment: Why don't you use `write.table`?

Comment: I am writing data to HDFS so dont want to give explicit path. I want let Hadoop decide which file to write `stdout`; after I do `cat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as.character() will help, just in

```
> cat(a$date)
15309 15310 15311 15312 15313 15314 15315 15316> 
> 
> cat(as.character(a$date))
2011-12-01 2011-12-02 2011-12-03 2011-12-04 2011-12-05 2011-12-06 2011-12-    07 2011-12-08> 
>
```

also

```
> cat(a$MDSE_ITEM_I)
1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3> 
> cat(as.character(a$MDSE_ITEM_I))
10 10 15 15 23 23 23 23>
```

HTH,
Bernhard

Comment: Yes this is a symptom fix but why this is needed. From the documentation of cat(): `cat is useful for producing output in user-defined functions. It converts its arguments to character vectors, concatenates them to a single character vector, appends the given sep = string(s) to each element and then outputs them.` So it does `converts its arguments to character vectors`.

Comment: Obviously, cat converts the date and the factors in form of their internal representation. Thus space and Information about which factors are equal and which are saved, readability of dates, date format and factor level names are lost. As shown, there is no Problem in fixing that, by giving the character representation of the data to cat if you want to send the character representation.

Comment: based on the @Bernhard approach final code is:
`a<-data.frame(apply(a,2,FUN=as.character),stringsAsFactors = F)
x<- sapply(1:nrow(a), FUN = function(row) {
  cat(a$MDSE_ITEM_I[row],",",a$CO_LOC_I[row],",",a$date[row],",",
      a$SLS_TYPE_GRP_C[row],",",a$NON_CLR_SLS_Q[row],"\n",sep='')})
rm(x)`